# What's wrong with my sed regex

Tags: json, unix, sed

I have a sed command to replace json key-value pairs in the format

```
"XXXXX" : "YYYYY"
```

or

```
"XXXXX" : YYYYY
```

Here is my sed command,

```
sed -i  's/\("$\$XXXX\$\$\"\s*:\s*\"\)[^\"]*/\1YYYY/'
```

Now I want to modify the above regex to update key-value pairs.

Example:

```
"XXXXX" : "YYYYY"
```

should be updated to

```
"XXXXX" : "ZZZZZ"
```

and

```
"XXXXX" : YYYYY
```

should be updated to

```
"XXXXX" : ZZZZZ
```

Note the difference, if value is with quotes, value should be updated with quotes and it value doesn't have quotes then, it should update it also

This is the sed command I came up with, but it doesn't work.

```
sed -i  's/\("$\$"qc.testset.ids"\$\$\"\s*:\s*"*\)[^\"]*/\1123123"*/'
```

Anything I missed here? How do I get my regex to support both format?

Comment: So you want to pass from `"XXXXX" : "YYYYY"` to `"XXXXX" : YYYYY`?

Comment: @fedorqui Removed the ambiguity in my description. Basically, I want my regex to update key in both format `"XXXXX" : "YYYYY"` and `"XXXXX" : YYYYY`.

Comment: Right. I did a little update to make it more clear. Anyway, can you show a desired output to make it easier to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use optional capture groups:

```
$ cat file
"XXXXX" : "YYYYY"
"XXXXX" : YYYYY
"XXXXX" : "YYYYY",  
"XXXXX" : YYYYY,

$ sed -r 's/^("XXXXX" : )(")?[^",]*(")?/\1\2ZZZZZ\3/' file
"XXXXX" : "ZZZZZ"
"XXXXX" : ZZZZZ
"XXXXX" : "ZZZZZ",  
"XXXXX" : ZZZZZ,
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. It works fine but if the key value pair is in the format `"XXXXX" : "YYYYY",` it is updated to `"XXXXX" : "ZZZZZ",` 
But `"XXXXX" : YYYYY,` is updated to `"XXXXX" : ZZZZZ`. Note the comma is missing. 

I tried to edit your regex but couldnt get it working, could you take a look at it.

`sed -r 's/^("XXXXX"\s*:\s*)(")?[^"]*(")?(,)?/\1\2NEW_VALUE\3\4/'`

Comment: This was never a specification so of course it wouldn't work as expected, luckily the fixed is trivial. You should make your questions clear and representative from the start.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Got answer in just an hour for which I was digging more than a day!

Comment: No problem, you would have got the answer in less then 10 minutes if you had posted the input example and expected output from the start, make sure you post clear questions and read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0):

This sed can also work:

```
sed '/^"XXXXX"/{s/YYYYY/ZZZZZ/}' file
```